# Can flutter or ionic mobile app interface with Thermapen through Bluetooth?

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, flutter, iot, hybrid-mobile-app

We are looking at developing a mobile application that interfaces with Thermapen (https://www.thermoworks.com/Thermapen-Blue) through Bluetooth for as part of our IoT integration.

We will eventually need mobile application for both Android and iOS platforms. We are looking at flutter or ionic as hybrid mobile framework so that we can have a common codebase across mobile platforms.

Can flutter or ionic mobile app interface with Thermapen through Bluetooth? What is the plugin/add-on to be used for bluetooth communication from these frameworks? Will that be a reliable solution to expand the interfaces to more bluetooth devices in the future?

Comment: Look at these plugins: https://github.com/Polidea/FlutterBleLib , https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue , https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
Finally, we went with developing Android (and separate iOS) app as the vendor (Thermoworks) had a different set of SDKs for interfacing from Android and iOS.